# eth0: kevent 2 may have been dropped

Tags: raspbian

i run my pi headless and i ssh in to it. i use rtorrent a bit. the pi is always on and until lately it has been fine. i run fsck regularly against the ext4 partition. however lately the pi has been crashing every few hours and i cannot ssh in. a reset always fixes the problem, but obviously its annoying. i tried `dmesg` and was surprised to see about 10000 lines of this:

```
[ 3180.082225] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: kevent 2 may have been dropped
```

what does this mean? is it the source of my problems? how can i make it stop?

this was also in the output (only once) as well:

```
[ 3634.360593] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: Failed to read register index 0x00000118
```

**os details:**

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.1.9+ #168 PREEMPT Sat Jul 14 18:56:31 BST 2012 armv6l GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux wheezy/sid \n \l
```

Comment: Well- If you put `-1` on my answer that it was obviously not deserved. Since the only answer, mine is what you tried so it did not deserve a downvote. So figure it your yourself and let us know. Cheers

Comment: @AwesomeUser unfortunately not. i just stopped using the pi. i'm guessing it was a dying sd card. either that or sid wreaking havoc. i'll be using the pi later on this year, so i'll get a new sd card and update the answer if it works fine with that...

Comment: @ppumkin we don't see your answer here so it may have been deleted. In that case you should delete your comment regarding your answer as well :-)

Answer (score 3):

is it the source of my problems?

It seems likely (so remove it as a possible cause and go from there)

what does this mean?

The network driver used by the rpi will not cope well with heavy traffic and high CPU usage. It will loose track of connections and in some cases memory causing the rpi to hang.

how can i make it stop?

"kevent 2 may have been dropped" can be avoided by asking the kernel to disable turbo networking by adding  `smsc95xx.turbo_mode=N` to /boot/cmdline.txt, nice-ing rtorrent and anything else CPU heavy, and limiting download speed and max connections in rtorrent.rc. increasing vm.min_free_kilobytes can also help but it's better to just limit system load.

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/309