# kevent 2 may have been dropped

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu, docker

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16 on my pi3 and I'm trying to pull docker images from he repository remotely( logged in via ssh) and keep running into the error

> smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: kevent 2 may have been dropped

which also leads to these "hung_task_timeout_secs and blocked for more than 120 seconds" messages

When doing some research similar people have encountered the error and are using

My question is what steps can one take to avoid this kind of thing in the future?

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Heavy cpu + network load due to deluge that causes my RPI2 to hang after a couple of weeks of activity. You can look at [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28186/1592) and [this issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/309) for more info, but I think it won't be something simple to fix. RPI USB/network subsystem has always had low performance and also haunted by every kind of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=160021&start=50) and [this issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/673), it seems it has been fixed in kernel version 4.9.24-v7+ since 17 April 2017 or so. I'll also try to upgrade my PI2 kernel.